# Run geth in light mode on Rinkeby and Raspberry

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, light-clients, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run `geth --light --cache 64 --rinkeby` but it stucks on

`INFO [02-12|08:58:16] IPC endpoint opened: /home/pi/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc`.

I am using geth on a Raspberry.

The full output is:

```
geth --light --cache 64 --rinkeby
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-arm/go1.7.4
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/pi/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth/lightchaindata cache=64 handles=1024
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 4 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 1035301 Engine: clique}"
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] Loaded most recent local header          number=10815 hash=d783a3…2cb71d td=21429
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] RLPx listener up                         self="enode://b8f1470420a00d38eef1d248c81fa6339af942bf2eaeb62b46ba26f3db6a0f1435b23486b741e5d998a681213e7cf467f3b1096497af10267499ac7b0f9099df@[::]:30303?discport=0"
WARN [02-12|08:58:16] Light client mode is an experimental feature 
ERROR[02-12|08:58:16] Failed to retrieve current release       err="can't fetch trie key ff59dc520c6c214bf3711461287c619f740a46852d93cc5a8e998966582e7cf3: no suitable peers available"
INFO [02-12|08:58:16] IPC endpoint opened: /home/pi/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc
```

I tried the same command on my macOS Mojave and it works fine, after opening IPC endpoint it continues importing blocks and states.

Should I assume it's a problem with the machine on which the geth is running?

Answer (score 0):

which version of geth are you using? I had the same problem on 1.7.3 then I upgraded to latest armv7 build which is 1.8.23 as of now. then blocks I could see block headers. I could not see my ethers on Pi and also was unable to find any peers. but after upgrade, it worked fine.